# How to call a forEach on an observable recursively

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am not sure if I gave question the right heading, but I wasn't sure as how shall I put it up. I have a service that I need to call to check if an item is to be disabled or not. I am unable to figure out as how can I check the same for subitems below and return the final list (not containing items and subitems that are disabled) -

```
    private filterWithPermissions(items: Item[] = []): Item[] {
        //filtering some root items
        let filteredItems = items.filter((item) => this.isItemDisabled(item));

        //checking if sub items exist and if they do, check each sub item's permission
        filteredItems.forEach((item) => (item.subItems = this.filterWithPermissions(item.subItems)));
        return filtered;
    }

    private isItemDisabled(item: Item) {
        return this.itemAPI.isEnabled(item.code).pipe(
            map((flag) => {
                return flag;
            })
        );
    }
```

Comment: `isItemDisabled` is an API call, i.e. a subscription, which means you can't directly `filter` on it. So map each `item` to `[item, isItemDisabled(item)]`, then either 1. [concatall](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concatall) then [toarray](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray), or 2. [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please? And yeah, `isItemDisabled` is an api call, and that's the whole thing that I believe I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: You can begin with `forkJoin(items.map(item => this.isItemDisabled(item)).subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: How will the submenus be handled? This statement here - `filteredItems.forEach((item) => (item.subItems = this.filterWithPermissions(item.subItems)));`, need not to change it?

Comment: `forkJoin(items.map(item => this.isItemDisabled(item).pipe(filter(flag => flag), switchMap(_ => this.filterWithPermissions(item.subItems)), tap(subItems => item.subItems = subItems))).subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: that indeed sound fascinating, i am surely gonna try it in a while and keep you posted. Thanks a ton mate.